# Pandas отказывается читать csv файлы

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Есть 2 csv файла в папке D:\compli_data, а именно: 
submission, весит 336 КБ 
train, весит 16936 КБ 
Весь фишка в том , что файл submission pandas читает , а файл train говорит что его не существует, в чем фокус? Pandas последней версии
[image: train]

[image: submission]

Comment: В вопросе должен быть код, который приводит к ошибке и желательно полный `error traceback`...

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-pandas-numpy-scipy-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 1):

Замените обратный слэш на прямой в пути к файлу или сделайте так:

```
table = pd.read_csv(r'D:\compile_data\...')
#                   ^
```

Чтобы понять как Python воспринимает путь:

```
In [6]: print('D:\compli_data\train.csv')
D:\compli_data  rain.csv
```

в данном случае `'\t'` - это символ табуляции

```
In [7]: print('D:\compli_data\submission.csv')
D:\compli_data\submission.csv
```

Comment: Учитывая слеши сложно понять, как второй кусок кода работает.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak, я добавил пример в ответ...

Comment: Я имел ввиду, почему у ОР выполняется вторая часть кода и появляется 'table' - по идее тоже должно валится. Возможно внутри Jupiter не обновляется, все стопорится на первой ошибке.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak, потому что `'D:\compli_data\submission.csv'` интерпретируется как правильный путь - посмотрите что второй `print()` напечатал...

Comment: Точно! Спасибо за пояснения.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри какое расширение у тебя в csv файле. У меня была такая ошибка, надо написать после указания пути к файлу encording = "ANSI"(может быть другая, от кодировки зависит). Кодировку можно посмотреть в нижнем правом углу при открытии csv файла в блокноте, открываешь, жмешь сохранить как, и в нижнем правом углу будет написана кодировка